# Download video from a website using chrome Inspect Element

Tags: google-chrome, xaml

I'm trying to download a video from a website. The link of the video sources is given like below when I inspect the video in chrome. I've watched few youtube videos, but none of the videos seem to match with the given link. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
https://ums-web-public-files.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ZoomRecording/Course_564/Routine_9186/15fb96a1-00f4-437b-8aa4-7d88135af5e2_7381.MP4
```

[Details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrcj4.png)